# Ubuntu 14: Apache Subversion Upgrade - Can't find version of SVN being used to serve the repo list

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, svn, ubuntu-14.04

I've been trying to upgrade an SVN server from version 1.8.8 to version 1.14.0. See the bottom of this description for the process that I've followed specifically. After executing that process, I've gone through and made sure to overwrite the binaries with the new ones provided in the installation, per the Release Notes on Apache Subversion's website.

When I go to the SVN webpage on a client, I still see the version 1.8.8:
[Collection of Repositories, Powered by Apache Subversion 1.8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv9cg.png)

I've checked the version of all the CLI clients: (svn --version comes back with 1.14, svnserve --version comes back with 1.14, etc.)

Clearly, there's a disconnect here regarding the way that I thought this works, and the way that it actually works. I cannot for the life of me figure out where the "1.8.8" version is coming from, or how to fix it.

The main problem occurs when I need to create a new repository, I will write "svnadmin create /repo/path repo_name" and I get a this when I browse to the new repo: [Could not open the requested SVN filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t777i.png%27). I am currently able to get around this problem by doing svnadmin create /repo/path --compatible-version 1.8, but, this really seems like an unnecessary workaround.

Does anyone have any idea where Apache is getting version 1.8 from? And, as a bonus question, do you have any clues on how I can get this upgraded to the same version as the toolset?

Steps followed to install newest version of Subversion and tools:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libsvn*
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libapr*
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libserf*

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install scons

sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install libtool

wget https://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/subversion/subversion-1.14.0.tar.gz
./get-deps.sh

cd apr
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

cd apr-util
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-apr=/usr
make
sudo make install

cd zlib
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

cd serf
// Here, I fixed test/test_buckets.c line 1237, which uses // instead of /**/
scons OPENSSL=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu PREFIX=/usr
scons check
sudo scons install

cd ../
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-amalgamation-3081101.zip
unzip sqlite-amalgamation-3081101.zip
mv sqlite-amalgamation-3081101 sqlite-amalgamation
./configure --with-serf=/usr --with-lz4=internal --with-utf8proc=internal
make
make check
sudo make install
sudo make install-tools

<manually replaced all binaries with new ones, since they installed in a different location>

sudo reboot
```

At this point, wondering if this is related to the mod_dav_svn plugin

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just upgrade the Linux system? Ubuntu 14.04 is AFAIK out of support.

Comment: It's not my call, but, it's definitely on my list of recommendations for "things that need to happen"

Answer (score 0):

./configure --with-lz4=internal --with-utf8proc=internal **--with-apache-libexecdir=/usr/lib/apache2/modules** --bindir=/usr/bin --libdir=/usr/lib **--with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs** --with-serf=/usr

When building subversion, I modified the configure line as above to get the mod_dav_svn.so to be generated